# Image blur effect in shaders

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, blur, post-processing

I want to do image effects such as screen blur in my game but I have a problem that it just darkens the screen slightly.

Here is the class for the FBO

```
GLuint m_fbo;
GLuint m_fboTexture;
GLuint m_fboDepthBuffer;

void FBO::Initialize(float width, float height)
{
    glGenFramebuffersEXT(1, &m_fbo);
    glGenTextures(1, &m_fboTexture);
    glGenRenderbuffersEXT(1, &m_fboDepthBuffer);

    glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, m_fbo);

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_fboTexture);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glGenerateMipmapEXT(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, (GLuint)width, (GLuint)height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
    glFramebufferTexture2DEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_EXT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_fboTexture, 0);

    glBindRenderbufferEXT(GL_RENDERBUFFER_EXT, m_fboDepthBuffer);
    glRenderbufferStorageEXT(GL_RENDERBUFFER_EXT, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24, (GLuint)width, (GLuint)height);
    glFramebufferRenderbufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT_EXT, GL_RENDERBUFFER_EXT, m_fboDepthBuffer);

    glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, 0);

    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}

void FBO::Bind()
{
    glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, m_fbo);
}

void FBO::UnBind()
{
   glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, 0);
}

void FBO::Clear()
{
    glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, m_fbo);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, 0);
}
```

This is how I set it up in my main class.

```
FBO m_fbo;//create an object

//initialize size
m_fbo.Initiliazie(screen_width, screen_height);
```

In my render function I do this

```
void Render()
{
   SetShaderProgram();//start shader program

   m_fbo.Bind();

   SetShaderImageSampler("texture", 0, m_fbo.m_fboTexture);
   SetShaderUniformVec2("size", (float)SCREEN_WIDTH, (float)SCREEN_HEIGHT);
   SetShaderUniformInt("kernel_size", ksize);

   //draws my texture
   m_spriteBatch->Draw(RecTangle(0, 0, (float)SCREEN_WIDTH, (float)SCREEN_HEIGHT));

   m_fbo.UnBind();

   EndShaderProgram();//end shader program
}
```

This is what SetShaderImageSampler function does:

```
void SetShaderImageSampler(char *sSamplerName, U32 nSlot, GLuint nHandle)
{
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + nSlot);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, nHandle);
    U32 nSamplerLoc = glGetUniformLocation(m_shaderProgram, sSamplerName);
    glUniform1iARB(nSamplerLoc, nSlot);
}
```

This is my spritebatch draw

```
void SpriteBatch::Draw(RecTangle rect)
{
    //draws it depending on its center
    float left = -(rect.right/2.0f);
    float right = left + (rect.right);
    float top = -(rect.bottom/2.0f);
    float bottom = top + (rect.bottom);

    //vertices: Vertex(x, y, z, u, v) coordinates
    m_vertex[0] = Vertex(left,  top,    0, 0, 0);
    m_vertex[1] = Vertex(right, top,    0, 1, 0);
    m_vertex[2] = Vertex(right, bottom, 0, 1, 1);
    m_vertex[3] = Vertex(left,  bottom, 0, 0, 1);

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(Vertex), &m_vertex[0].m_fX);

    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(Vertex), &m_vertex[0].m_fU);

    glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 4);

    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    glColor4f(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
}
```

This is my frag shader

```
uniform sampler2D texture;
uniform vec2 size;
uniform int kernel_size;

void main (void)  
{ 
    vec4 color = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    vec2 st = gl_TexCoord[0].st;
    vec2 texel = 1.0/size;

    int sum = 0;
    for(int i=-kernel_size; i <= kernel_size; i++) 
    {
            vec4 value = texture2D(texture, st + vec2(0.0, texel.y * i));
            int factor = kernel_size+1 - abs((float)i);
            color += value * factor;
            sum += factor;
    }
    color /= sum;

    gl_FragColor = color;
    gl_FragColor.a = 1.0;
}
```

Its not working too well.  I tried changing the shader to do something else but it just slighly darkens it no matter what.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14107979/blur-an-image-of-specific-part-rectangular-circular/14108694#14108694

Answer (score 2):

The unbind should be

```
glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, 0);
```

Comment: Wow I did not see that.  Well its not black anymore.  Now I tried to do some screen blur but its not doing anything.  I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you haven't included enough code but I don't see you actually rendering anything in your Render method.

You have some calls the first of which I assume activate's the context, then you bind the frame buffer and link the shader variables, but next I would expect a call to render a quad / mesh somehow (i.e with a glBegin/glEnd section or a vertex buffer bind and render.)

Comment: I didnt included it because I thought it wasnt necessary.  Its my first time that I am doing image effects so I am not sure how to initialize it.  But right after the EndShaderProgram I am drawing objects such a cube and a plane for the floor which they have their own shaders.  So I am not sure if the Screen Blur should be together with the other objects shaders or the blur has to be in their own shader.  Ill update the rest of the render so you can see what I am talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, generally to do post processing effects you would render the scene with the frame buffer active. Then render a full screen quad with your post process (blur) shader active and the frame buffer textures bound as samplers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I completely forgot to render the quad.  I rendered it now but instead of bluring it, it just darkens it.  I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Nevenmind I have it working now.  I was calling Bind and UnBind in the wrong place.